How do I put text in front of an image when using PySide?
I am creating a program using PySide to build the GUI. Everything works perfectly, except for one of my loops. The basic gist is I am trying to put text in front of a button image, but I am instead seeing the button image on the left, and the button text to the right of that image.
Here is the button setup loop:
for i, buttonText in enumerate(self.buttonTextLeft):
    cBut=QPushButton(buttonText, self)
    cBut.setIcon(QIcon(resPixmap))
    cBut.setIconSize(resPixmap.size())
    cBut.setStyleSheet(f"font-family: {self.language}; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; background-color: transparent; border: none;")
    cBut.setGeometry(0, int(self.bTL*self.height()),int(self.topButtonWidth*self.width()),int(self.leftButtonWidth*self.height()))
    cBut.clicked.connect(lambda checked,index=i:self.optionButtonsClickLeft(index))
    self.optionButtonsLeft.append(cBut)
    self.bTL+=self.leftButtonWidth

As I said, everything else is perfect, except the text won't get in FRONT of the button.
NOTE:
buttonTextLeft is an array filled with the strings I want to show in front of each button
bTL and leftButtonWidth are numerical values used only for the placement of each button...these work fine and having nothing to do with the problem.

Buttons are made of one icon and/or one text label that are supposed to always be placed side by side by convention. If you want to display the text on top (as in superimposed over) the icon, then don't set the text, and add a QLabel as its child, possibly using a layout manager. Note that setting fixed and arbitrary geometries of widgets is always discouraged, and layout managers should always be preferred instead.

Ended up getting it fixed after a few hours of troubleshooting, (set the button image as the background), and even managed to re-write some of the variable calculations so that the buttons get re-sized depending on the size of the screen, which was only a potential problem that is now resolved as well.
new code:
    for i,buttonText in enumerate(self.buttonTextLeft):
        cBut=QPushButton(buttonText,self)
        cBut.setStyleSheet(f"font-family:{self.language};
                            font-size:12px;
                            font-weight:bold;
                            color:{self.colorGold};
                            background-color:transparent;
                            border:none;
                            background-image:url('MDButton3.png');")
        cBut.setFixedSize(buttonSize,buttonSize+2)
        #Calculates the y position for each button
        yPos=spacing*(i+1)+buttonSize*i
        cBut.setGeometry(
            spaceFromTopAndBottom,
            yPos+spaceFromTopAndBottom,
            int(self.topButtonWidth*self.width()),
            buttonSize)
        cBut.clicked.connect(lambda checked,index=i: self.optionButtonsClickLeft(index))
        self.optionButtonsLeft.append(cBut)

